# How to do different actions in 1 command for SQL (subquery)

Tags: sql, oracle11g

`CREATE TABLE PRESCRIPTION (
    DID         VARCHAR2(20)
        CONSTRAINT Prescription_DID_NotNull NOT NULL,
    PID         VARCHAR2(20)
        CONSTRAINT Prescription_PID_NotNull NOT NULL,
    PrescDT     DATE
        CONSTRAINT Prescription_PrescDT_NotNull NOT NULL,
    PharName        VARCHAR2(30)
        CONSTRAINT Prescription_PharName_NotNull NOT NULL,
    Tradename       VARCHAR2(30)
        CONSTRAINT Prescription_TradeName_NotNull NOT NULL,
    Remarks     VARCHAR(128),
CONSTRAINT Prescription_PK PRIMARY KEY (DID, PID, PrescDT, PharName, TradeName),
CONSTRAINT Prescription_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (DID) REFERENCES DOCTOR (DID),
CONSTRAINT Prescription_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (PID) REFERENCES PATIENT (PID),
CONSTRAINT Prescription_FK3 FOREIGN KEY (PharName, Tradename) REFERENCES DRUG (PharName, Tradename)
);`

`-- Insert sample records to the relational table PRESCRIPTION
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292812','S5503507C', sysdate-3,'Biomed','Opioids','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292812','S4657986F', sysdate-21,'Medmed Shine','Zovirax','Apply to the infected areas 3 times daily');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292812','S6335549H', sysdate-21,'Medcineco','Prednisone','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292812','7546975624', sysdate-3,'Kleenxin','Dextromethorphan','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292812','7546975624', sysdate-3,'Biomed','Expectorants','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292812','S5436485D', sysdate-21,'Medmed Shine','Corticosteroids','Inhale when attack');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292812','S5434018K', sysdate-21,'Biomed','Silvadene','Apply to the affected area 3 times daily' );
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292812','S5434018K', sysdate-21,'Biomed','Ibuprofen','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal' );
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292812','S3338992D', sysdate-21,'Medcineco','Panadol','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3183671','S5315919S', sysdate-19,'Medmed Shine','Opioids','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3183671','S6125888E', sysdate-19,'Biomed','Acetaminophen','Apply to the affected areas 3 times daily');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3183671','S5225164A', sysdate-19,'Kleenxin','Propranolol','1 tablet daily after breakfast');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3183671','S5234165A', sysdate-19,'Biomed','Ibuprofen','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292885','S5311385K', sysdate-19,'Biomed','Ibuprofen','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292885','S4535694G', sysdate-9,'Peter Martin','Dextromethorphan', '1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292885','S4535694G', sysdate-9,'Biomed','Expectorants', '1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292885','S6694865S', sysdate-2,'Medmed Shine','Chloramphenicol','Apply 3 times daily');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292885','S5503507C', sysdate-14,'Kleenxin','Propranolol','1 tablet daily after breakfast');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292885','S8104586F', sysdate-14,'Peter Martin','Beclomethasone','Inhave when affected');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292885','B366548', sysdate-14,'Medmed Shine','Anxiolytic','1 tablet daily');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292885','S5476812D', sysdate-14,'Peter Martin','Aspirin','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292885','S6654782F', sysdate-10,'Medmed Shine','Acetaminophen','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292885','S6654782F', sysdate-10,'Kleenxin','Salt water','Gargling frequently with warm, salt water');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292848','B765598', sysdate-1,'Kleenxin','Opioids','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3293063','S6125888E', sysdate-21,'Medmed Shine','Neosporin','Apply to the affected area 3 times daily');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3293063','S6654782F', sysdate-21,'Medmed Shine','Dextromethorphan','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3293063','S6654782F', sysdate-21,'Medcineco','Expectorants','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3293063','S4573521A', sysdate-20,'Kleenxin','Codeine','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3293063','S4573521A', sysdate-20,'Medcineco','Expectorants','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3293063','S6654782F', sysdate-1,'Peter Martin','Panadol','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3293063','S5234165A', sysdate-19,'Kleenxin','Beclomethasone','Inhale when affected');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3293063','S6458795J', sysdate-19,'Kleenxin','Beclomethasone','Inhave when affected');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3293063','S5815447L', sysdate-19,'Peter Martin','Methicillin','Apply to the infected area 3 times daily');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3293063','S4535694G', sysdate-18,'Peter Martin','Prednisone','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3332949','S6575880E', sysdate-18,'Kleenxin','Naproxen','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3332949','S6575880E', sysdate-18,'Medcineco','Ibuprofen','2 to 3 tablets every 4 to 6 hours');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3332949','S5540866J', sysdate-18,'Kleenxin','Acetaminophen','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3332949','S5540866J', sysdate-18,'Kleenxin','Salt water','Gargling frequently with warm, salt water');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3332949','S4531852D', sysdate-17,'Medmed Shine','Ibuprofen','Arrange for physical therapy.');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3332949','S6694865S', sysdate-17,'Medmed Shine','Neosporin','Apply to the affected area 3 times daily');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3257095','S3994647E', sysdate-17,'Peter Martin','Opioids','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3257095','S5672186F', sysdate-17,'Peter Martin','Opioids','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3231951','S6694865S', sysdate-16,'Kleenxin','Zovirax','Apply to the infected areas 3 times daily');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3231951','S3338992D', sysdate-16,'Medmed Shine','Aspirin','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3332949','S5567841E', sysdate-16,'Medcineco','Emadine','Apply 3 times daily');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3332949','S3338992D', sysdate-15,'Peter Martin','Corticosteroids','Inhale when attack');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3332949','S5311385K', sysdate-15,'Medcineco','Dextromethorphan','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3332949','S5311385K', sysdate-15,'Biomed','Expectorants','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3332949','S5540866J', sysdate-15,'Medcineco','Ibuprofen','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3332949','S3338992D', sysdate-14,'Peter Martin','Codeine','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3332949','S3338992D', sysdate-14,'Biomed','Expectorants','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3332949','S5567841E', sysdate-14,'Kleenxin','Naproxen','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3332949','S5567841E', sysdate-14,'Kleenxin','Ibuprofen','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal.');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3332950','S6575880E', sysdate-14,'Medmed Shine','Ibuprofen','Arrange for physical therapy');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3332950','S6550748A', sysdate-13,'Medmed Shine','Opioids','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3233339','S6694865S', sysdate-13,'Biomed','Penicillin','Apply to the infected area 3 times daily');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3233339','S4573521A', sysdate-13,'Kleenxin','Propranolol','1 tablet daily after breakfast');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3233339','S5434018K', sysdate-13,'Medcineco','Emadine','Apply 3 times daily');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3233339','S5672186F', sysdate-13,'Peter Martin','Beclomethasone','Inhale when affected');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3233339','S5434018K', sysdate-13,'Peter Martin','Salicylic acid','Apply to the infected area 3 times daily');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3183671','S5784263H', sysdate-12,'Medmed Shine','Ibuprofen','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3183671','S5311385K', sysdate-12,'Medmed Shine','Opioids','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3183671','S3994647E', sysdate-12,'Peter Martin','Dextromethorphan','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3183671','S3994647E', sysdate-12,'Kleenxin','Expectorants','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3257338','S6125888E', sysdate-12,'Medmed Shine','Opioids','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3257338','S6225319E', sysdate-12,'Medmed Shine','Ibuprofen','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3257338','S5234165A', sysdate-12,'Medmed Shine','Opioids','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3257338','S6575880E', sysdate-11,'Medmed Shine','Opioids','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3257338','S5540866J', sysdate-11,'Biomed','Acetaminophen','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3257338','S5540866J', sysdate-11,'Biomed','Doxycycline','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3257338','S5570143E', sysdate-10,'Medmed Shine','Opioids','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3257338','S5614758D', sysdate-10,'Peter Martin','Dextromethorphan','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3257338','S5614758D', sysdate-10,'Kleenxin','Expectorants','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3257338','S5540866J', sysdate-9,'Biomed','Acetaminophen','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3257338','S5540866J', sysdate-9,'Biomed','Doxycycline','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3257338','S5815447L', sysdate-9,'Kleenxin','Naproxen','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3257338','S5815447L', sysdate-9,'Medmed Shine','Ibuprofen','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal.');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3257338','S6458795J', sysdate-9,'Medcineco','Silvadene','Apply to the affected area 3 times daily');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3257338','S6458795J', sysdate-9,'Medmed Shine','Ibuprofen','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3257338','S5234165A', sysdate-7,'Biomed','Cromolyn sodium','Apply 3 times daily');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3257338','S5540866J', sysdate-7,'Biomed','Dextromethorphan','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3257338','S5540866J', sysdate-7,'Medmed Shine','Doxycycline','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3183646','S5570143E', sysdate-7,'Medmed Shine','Ibuprofen','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3183646','S5672186F', sysdate-6,'Biomed','Dextromethorphan','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3183646','S5672186F', sysdate-6,'Kleenxin','Expectorants','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3183646','S6458795J', sysdate-6,'Biomed','Dextromethorphan','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3183646','S6458795J', sysdate-6,'Kleenxin','Expectorants','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3183646','S5570143E', sysdate-6,'Medmed Shine','Cyclophosphamide','Procedure is to be done at the hospital.');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3217643','S6458795J', sysdate,'Kleenxin','Prednisone','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3217546','S5311385K', sysdate,'Medmed Shine','Ibuprofen','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3217546','S5311385K', sysdate,'Medmed Shine','Codeine','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3217546','S5311385K', sysdate,'Biomed','Expectorants','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3232974','S5815447L', sysdate,'Medmed Shine','Opioids','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3232974','S3994647E', sysdate,'Medmed Shine','Neosporin','Apply to the affected area 3 times daily');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3232974','S5234165A', sysdate,'Medcineco','Azithromycin','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3232974','S6575880E', sysdate,'Kleenxin','Opioids','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3254117','S5225164A', sysdate,'Kleenxin','Opioids','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3254117','S5784263H', sysdate,'Medmed Shine','Ibuprofen','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');`

I want to find the drug(tradename), with only the month and year it has been prescribed and my condition is to list the drug if only it has been prescribed more than 3 times per month.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at your sample data, none of the fruits have been purchased three times in one month. In fact, none of them have been purchased three times. You'll get more answers if you fix that, and if you provide CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements that we can run instead of descriptions we have to reverse engineer.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Alright, i will, give me a moment, as there're too much information

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Added in my `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements, needed some time to do the formatting.

Comment: You do not describe a table where the drugs are prescribed. To simplify things, you could also create an [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com) with the data that everyone could use to simplify things.

Comment: @MT0 hmm, why would i need to describe where it was prescribed

Comment: @Zac You had asked - `with only the month and year it has been prescribed and my condition is to list the drug if only it has been prescribed more than 3 times per month.` If you don't have a table containing details of when it is prescribed then the question can't be answered.

Comment: @MT0 i have them actually, but it was given in `sysdate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct answer to you question would seem to be aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
SELECT FRUIT, TO_CHAR(DATEOFPURCHASE, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY FRUIT, TO_CHAR(DATEOFPURCHASE, 'YYYY-MM')
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3;
```

However, your sample results suggest that the real question is:  What months have three different fruits purchased in them and what are the fruits?  For this question, you can use analytic functions:

```
SELECT FRUIT, TO_CHAR(DATEOFPURCHASE, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             COUNT(DISTINCT fruit) OVER (PARTITION BY TO_CHAR(DATEOFPURCHASE, 'YYYY-MM')) as numfruit
      FROM TABLE t
     ) t
WHERE numfruit = 3;
```

Comment: for `HAVING COUNT(*) = 3` will only show those that have been bought 3 times, how do i do if more than 3 times

Comment: You would use `>= 3`.

Comment: by changing it to `HAVING COUNT(*) < 3` ?

Answer (score 0):

Working around a few issues in your sample data:

1. The DDL has foreign keys referencing tables which you haven't described - I removed those references.
2. The sample data uses `SYSDATE` - anyone running the query will get different answers depending on which day of the month they run it. I've replaced it with a fixed date.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b87bd/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE PRESCRIPTION (
    DID         VARCHAR2(20)
        CONSTRAINT Prescription_DID_NotNull NOT NULL,
    PID         VARCHAR2(20)
        CONSTRAINT Prescription_PID_NotNull NOT NULL,
    PrescDT     DATE
        CONSTRAINT Prescription_PrescDT_NotNull NOT NULL,
    PharName        VARCHAR2(30)
        CONSTRAINT Prescription_PharName_NotNull NOT NULL,
    Tradename       VARCHAR2(30)
        CONSTRAINT Prescription_TradeName_NotNull NOT NULL,
    Remarks     VARCHAR(128),
CONSTRAINT Prescription_PK PRIMARY KEY (DID, PID, PrescDT, PharName, TradeName)
);

-- Insert sample records to the relational table PRESCRIPTION
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292812','S5503507C', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+3,'Biomed','Opioids','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292812','S4657986F', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+21,'Medmed Shine','Zovirax','Apply to the infected areas 3 times daily');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292812','S6335549H', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+21,'Medcineco','Prednisone','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292812','7546975624', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+3,'Kleenxin','Dextromethorphan','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292812','7546975624', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+3,'Biomed','Expectorants','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292812','S5436485D', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+21,'Medmed Shine','Corticosteroids','Inhale when attack');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292812','S5434018K', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+21,'Biomed','Silvadene','Apply to the affected area 3 times daily' );
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292812','S5434018K', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+21,'Biomed','Ibuprofen','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal' );
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292812','S3338992D', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+21,'Medcineco','Panadol','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3183671','S5315919S', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+19,'Medmed Shine','Opioids','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3183671','S6125888E', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+19,'Biomed','Acetaminophen','Apply to the affected areas 3 times daily');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3183671','S5225164A', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+19,'Kleenxin','Propranolol','1 tablet daily after breakfast');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3183671','S5234165A', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+19,'Biomed','Ibuprofen','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292885','S5311385K', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+19,'Biomed','Ibuprofen','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292885','S4535694G', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+9,'Peter Martin','Dextromethorphan', '1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292885','S4535694G', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+9,'Biomed','Expectorants', '1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292885','S6694865S', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+2,'Medmed Shine','Chloramphenicol','Apply 3 times daily');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292885','S5503507C', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+14,'Kleenxin','Propranolol','1 tablet daily after breakfast');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292885','S8104586F', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+14,'Peter Martin','Beclomethasone','Inhave when affected');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292885','B366548', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+14,'Medmed Shine','Anxiolytic','1 tablet daily');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292885','S5476812D', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+14,'Peter Martin','Aspirin','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292885','S6654782F', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+10,'Medmed Shine','Acetaminophen','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292885','S6654782F', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+10,'Kleenxin','Salt water','Gargling frequently with warm, salt water');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3292848','B765598', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+1,'Kleenxin','Opioids','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3293063','S6125888E', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+21,'Medmed Shine','Neosporin','Apply to the affected area 3 times daily');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3293063','S6654782F', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+21,'Medmed Shine','Dextromethorphan','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3293063','S6654782F', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+21,'Medcineco','Expectorants','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3293063','S4573521A', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+20,'Kleenxin','Codeine','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3293063','S4573521A', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+20,'Medcineco','Expectorants','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3293063','S6654782F', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+1,'Peter Martin','Panadol','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3293063','S5234165A', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+19,'Kleenxin','Beclomethasone','Inhale when affected');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3293063','S6458795J', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+19,'Kleenxin','Beclomethasone','Inhave when affected');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3293063','S5815447L', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+19,'Peter Martin','Methicillin','Apply to the infected area 3 times daily');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3293063','S4535694G', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+18,'Peter Martin','Prednisone','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3332949','S6575880E', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+18,'Kleenxin','Naproxen','1 tablet, 3 times daily after meal');
INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION VALUES('3332949','S6575880E', TO_DATE( '150101','YYMMDD')+18,'Medcineco','Ibuprofen','2 to 3 tablets every 4 to 6 hours');
```

**Query 1**:

```
-- I want to find the drug(tradename), with only the month and year it has
-- been prescribed and my condition is to list the drug if only it has been
-- prescribed more than 3 times per month.

SELECT Tradename,
       TRUNC( PrescDT, 'MM' ) AS Month
FROM   PRESCRIPTION
GROUP BY Tradename, TRUNC( PrescDT, 'MM' )
HAVING COUNT(1) > 3
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b87bd/2/0)**:

```
|    TRADENAME |                     MONTH |
|--------------|---------------------------|
|    Ibuprofen | January, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
| Expectorants | January, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
```